# Gstreamer pipeline for converting files with optional audio/video

Tags: gstreamer

I am using the following pipeline to convert an flv file to mp4.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv -e filesrc location="c.flv" ! flvdemux name=demux \
    demux.audio ! queue ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! faac bitrate=32000 ! mux. \
    demux.video ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc speed-preset=superfast tune=zerolatency psy-tune=grain sync-lookahead=5 bitrate=480 key-int-max=50 ref=2  ! mux. \
    mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location="c.mp4"
```

The problem is when (for example) audio is missing, the pipeline gets stuck. (Same thing happens if just hooking a `fakesink` to `demux.audio`).

I need a way for the filters to ignore missing tracks, or produce empty tracks.